# how to interpret multiple venn diagram

Tags: math, venn-diagram

Could some one explain the logic behind multiple Venn diagram by explaining what these numbers represent in the picture. Thanx in advance.

[image]

Comment: technically not *completely* on-topic here; you might have better luck at http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number in each location represents the number of items that can only be there and nowhere else.

For example there is exactly one item that is both `S` and `r` and also not in `E` or `R`.

There are two items that are in `S`, `r`, and `E` and not in `R`.

There are three items that are in `E` and `r` and also not in `S` or `R`.

Four items in only `r` and nowhere else

etc.

Conveniently enough, because all of the categories are mutually exclusive, you can find the number of items in any arbitrary category by adding up the sub-categories that make it up.

For example, the number of items in S and r total are 1+9+2+8 = 20